# Is there a way to declare a date variable in PL/SQL SELECT

Tags: sql, date, plsql, subquery

I'm using several sub-queries to pull data from the same table for several date ranges. Is there a way to set a date variable so I don't have to continually edit the date ranges?

For example:

```
Select A.Name,
    ,CASE
    WHEN B.WK1 IS NULL
    THEN 0
    ELSE B.WK1
    END as WK1

    ,CASE
    WHEN C.WK2 IS NULL
    THEN 0
    ELSE C.WK2
    END AS WK2

FROM

    (SELECT DISTINCT NAME
    FROM NAMES) A

    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT NAME,
    SUM(SALES) as WK1

    FROM SALES
    WHERE DATE between 1-JAN-2000 and 7-JAN-2000
    GROUP BY NAME) B
    ON NAME

    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT NAME,
    SUM(SALES) as WK2

    FROM SALES
    WHERE DATE between 8-JAN-2000 and 15-JAN-2000
    GROUP BY NAME) C
    ON NAME
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is have a rolling multi-week set from a single date.

Comment: What tool are you using to execute the query?

Comment: Bob - I'm using Toad 11.6

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your Date values with bind variables (such as :date1) as below. The first time you run your query Toad will ask you for values for these variables.After that Toad will remember the values you had entered and so it will be pre populated with the same values so you dont have to type them again. You need to make sure that you select the right data type as well.

```
Select A.Name,
    ,CASE
    WHEN B.WK1 IS NULL
    THEN 0
    ELSE B.WK1
    END as WK1

    ,CASE
    WHEN C.WK2 IS NULL
    THEN 0
    ELSE C.WK2
    END AS WK2

FROM

    (SELECT DISTINCT NAME
    FROM NAMES) A

    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT NAME,
    SUM(SALES) as WK1

    FROM SALES
    WHERE DATE between :date1 and :date2
    GROUP BY NAME) B
    ON NAME

    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT NAME,
    SUM(SALES) as WK2

    FROM SALES
    WHERE DATE between :date3 and :date4
    GROUP BY NAME) C
    ON NAME
```

Comment: Thank you - I'll check that out. Out of curiosity - would I need to re-declare the variables if I wanted to change the dates? So if I wanted the first two weeks of a month (January) and the next time I ran the script I wanted the first two weeks of say...February - I'd need to change all four dates, right?

Comment: you dont need to re-declare the variables..you need to enter the new values next time you run

Comment: Ah, ok. Understood. Thanks again.